# Load custom PHP on a custom URL via a plugin

Tags: plugins, permalinks

I am looking into having a plugin developed that loads a PHP script (`myscript.php`) on a custom URL. It's very important to achieve this functionality with a plugin. Example:

- `example.com/myscript` - loads myscript.php
- `example.com/myscript/example` - prints out "example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is_page()`. The `is_page()` function accepts page title, slug or id. [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

```
<?php 
if(is_page('myscript')) {
    include '/path/to/myscript.php';
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

To add it to the content, you have two options

**1. Find the content function in your template**

Find either `the_content()` or `get_the_content()` in your template. Place it immediately after that function (or before if you want it before).

**2. Add A Filter**

Move the above code into your theme's `functions.php` file and wrap it in a function. Then add a filter to `the_content()` to make it include your new function. Your code should look something like this:

```
function my_the_content_filter(){
    if(is_page('myscript')) {
        include '/path/to/myscript.php';
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I put this into my plugin file? myplugin.php ?

Comment: Managed to use it. The problem I have now is that it is loaded in the beginning of the page, not in the content area. Any idea?

Comment: Where did you place this code? In what file?

Comment: @MariusS see my updated answer